# Amplifying an electromagnet's generated field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Given an electromagnet like this:

[image]

which is essentially an iron casing with coils inside:

[image]

Is it right that the centre disc would have one polarity whilst the outer housing another?

To boost the field generated at the tip of the core, could a permanent magnet be placed on the bottom of the outside housing? If not, are there good ways for amplifying the field generated?

Comment: Yes, the core is one pole of the magnet and the external shielding/magnetic return path is another. If you put a permanent magnet into such a device you will get a much stronger field than you can expect from the magnetization by the current itself, but it will basically be a permanent magnet. If you want much larger fields than the 1-1.5T that you can get from a good permanent magnet, then you will have to buy a superconducting magnet.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm wondering if there's a way to boost the magnetic field at the core. If I place a permanent magnet on the bottom of the outside housing, it will indeed be a permanent magnet because of the magnetic housing, but it'll be rather weak at the core because of distance. But will the permanent magnet increase the field at the core when current flows through the winding?

Comment: If you place a permanent magnet at the bottom not much will happen. The magnetic field will penetrate somewhat, but the field lines will close towards the wrong end of the device. You can place a thin permanent magnet on top of the core or inside the core, if you want, which will give you a strong permanent magnet. Since a good permanent magnet will basically saturate the core material, any additional current trough the device won't do much for you. Like I said, if you want more field, ferromagnetic materials are not the way to go, superconductors are.

Comment: If you want to calculate numerically what will happen in these situations, you can use a tool like FEMM (http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) and there are many others, but FEMM is about as easy to use as they come. If you are interested, try it, learn how to use it and develop an intuition for simple magnetic systems, then you can move on to other tools that are more powerful but also require more knowledge to use.

Comment: @CuriousOne "You can place a thin permanent magnet on top of the core or inside the core, if you want, which will give you a strong permanent magnet" How come it'd be a "strong" permanent magnet?

Comment: @Kar: Because it will magnetize a much larger volume of the core. There are limits to that, of course, but, again, one can't increase the field this way. We can only use whatever field we have better. If you have ever seen a 12T superconducting magnet in the lab and you have felt the magnetic field on a screwdriver from a meter away (it is not advisable to go much closer, lest you don't mind puncturing the cryostat), then you know what a "strong" magnetic field looks like. But, again, technologically that's a different ballgame.

Comment: @CuriousOne You mentioned that the permanent magnet will saturate the core and current won't generate much of a field. I've found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9HyyGdnmb0) in which the permanent magnet seems to boost the field. Do you know why the magnet here amplifies the field?

Comment: That's sort of a constant magnetization version of a "magnetic amplifier": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_amplifier. As shown it switches the  magnetization by the permanent magnet, however, it does not actually increase the max. force that one could get out of the same permanent magnets in a different configuration, so I wouldn't talk about "amplification" in the sense that I understood from your original question and the name is a slight misnomer. The permanent magnet doesn't actually increase the electromagnet's field or vie versa.